# Binance API Futures - {'code': -1117, 'msg': 'Invalid side.'}

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

I'm trying to place a future position with [/fapi/v1/order](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#new-order-trade).

I keep encounter the error `{'code': -1117, 'msg': 'Invalid side.'}`. 
[More info on code 1117](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#11xx-request-issues)

Actual pseudo code

```
futures.orders.create(
            symbol='ADAUSDT',
            market_type="TRAILING_STOP_MARKET",
            position='LONG',
            activationPrice=1.80,
            callbackRate=2.0
        )
```

I've tried `['BOTH', 'BUY/LONG', 'SELL/SHORT', 'LONG', 'SHORT', 'BUY', 'SELL']` but the same erros keeps coming back, so what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized you got two `side` parameters; `positionSide` and `side`. `positionSide` was set but `side` was not.

Additional information:

There are only two available values for the `side` parameter of the order endpoint, one is `BUY` another is `SELL`.
If you want to place an order under the hedge mode, please use another parameter `positionSide` along with the `side` parameter.

- positionSide=LONG&side=BUY -> represents open long position
- positionSide=LONG&side=SELL -> represents close long position
- positionSide=SHORT&side=SELL -> represents open short position
- positionSide=SHORT&side=BUY -> represents close short position

Hope this helps future people : )